# After Full GC, young generation collection decreases 10 times

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Here I have an extract of my gc.log:

2013-02-28T12:02:13.209+0100: 1486457.849: [GC 1486457.850: [ParNew
 3483368K->96838K(3774912K), **0.2273030 secs**] 8085678K->4710336K(49912256K), 0.2278070 secs] [Times: user=1.54 sys=0.01, real=0.23 secs]

2013-02-28T12:02:26.551+0100: 1486471.191: [GC 1486471.191: [ParNew
 3452358K->125528K(3774912K), **0.2386800 secs**] 8065856K->4748772K(49912256K), 0.2392150 secs] [Times: user=1.64 sys=0.01, real=0.24 secs]

2013-02-28T12:02:27.398+0100: 1486472.038: [**Full GC** 1486472.039: [CMS: 4623244K->3323834K(46137344K), 3.0873920 secs] 5034629K->3323834K(49912256K), [CMS Perm : 97619K->54323K(98304K)], 3.0878880 secs] [Times: user=3.04 sys=0.01, real=3.08 secs]

2013-02-28T12:02:42.758+0100: 1486487.398: [GC 1486487.399: [ParNew
 3355519K->50321K(3774912K), **0.0289980 secs**] 6679353K->3374156K(49912256K), 0.0295550 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]

2013-02-28T12:02:59.045+0100: 1486503.685: [GC 1486503.685: [ParNew
 3405841K->71853K(3774912K), **0.0316570 secs**] 6729676K->3395688K(49912256K), 0.0321860 secs] [Times: user=0.22 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]

After a Full GC (because of perm space exhausted), the young generation collections decreases from 0,23 seconds to 0,03 seconds (10 times).

I have to find out the reason why the perm space becomes full, but what I don't understand is why the young generation collection time decreases 10 times because of the Full GC.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks,
Joan.

Comment: Well you can see it's increasing again afterwards, so the logical view is that there's not much in that space after a Full GC does a proper clear-up. You could consider just increasing the PermGen space and seeing if it's stable at a higher value.

Answer (score 1):

With the logs mentioned , i can tell few points .

The reason can be :

As the program runs, allocations occur and referencing takes place . Short-lived objects die and rest are promoted to survivor space or perm space .

Possible situation of referencing are as follows .

1) objects in eden space (younger generation) and survivor space  reference objects in perm space and tenured space making them live longer .

2) sometimes objects in perm space and tenured space references younger generation objects(in eden space and survivor space) .

Since garbage collection in tenured and perm space are not as frequent as younger generation .

There might be situation where object say **obj1** in perm space or tenured space are no longer referenced and are ready to be claimed by GC , so this **obj1** is waiting for GC, which happens infrequently .Again this **obj1** could have had references to objects in survivor and eden space . So  this objects in eden space and survivor space  referenced by **obj1** are not eligible for garbage collection . So there might be many objects like this in eden space and survivor space which  are being referenced by objects like **obj1** from perm space which leads to more number of objects in eden and survivor space .So minor GC takes more time .

In full GC ,objects like **obj1** are collected ,so no of objects in eden and survivor referenced by objects like **obj1** are also claimed by GC leading to less no of objects in eden and survivor space . Since number of objects are less, minor GC takes less time . If you observe further logs slowly minor Gc time is again increasing(0.0289980 secs ,0.0316570 as mentioned in your logs) ,  it might increase till next FULL GC .

You can also observe pattern of GC time before Full GC , it is increasing .(0.2273030 secs,0.2386800 secs as mentioned in your logs)